# Basemap ValueError: projection cannot cross pole

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm getting this error with the code below:
`ValueError: mill projection cannot cross pole`

```
lower_bound = 38.576311
upper_bound = 41.031715
left_bound = -78.929565
right_bound = -75.039918

m = Basemap(projection = 'mill', llcrnrlat = lower_bound, urcrnrlat = upper_bound,
                llcrnrlon = left_bound, urcrnrlon = right_bound, resolution = 'i')
```

I opened a new file in my IDE and copied and pasted the code from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mill.html). I ran it and it gave me the same error. I've also tried `projection = 'merc'` and the error still pops up. What causes this error to pop up how can I fix it? I have never come across this error while using basemap until now.

Comment: The code itself runs fine, so I guess the information here is not sufficient to find the problem.

Comment: I'd agree with you if I only provided my code without any other context. In that case, I wouldn't have posted here. However, I went to the docs (link above) and copied and pasted their code in a new file and I'm still getting that same error, which drove me to post here.

Comment: Ok, but 99% of all people can go to the docs, copy the code and run it without problem. Hence, there must be something special about what you are doing and that must be part of the question. Always think about reproducibility.

Comment: What version of python/matplotlib/basemap/numpy do you have installed? I just ran both your code and the documentation code in a new window and it's fine, so must be something with your environment.